# How to give dynamically height to div in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

Could you please tell me how to give dynamically height to div in angularjs? Actually i have one scrolling div (have content in that ). When I give 100px height, I am able to see all the content.

But I need to give height to that div **(window -header -footer)**

```
<ion-scroll direction="y" style="height: 100px">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="obj in data.data">
        <div class="col">
          {{obj.schDepart}}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          {{obj.expDepart}}
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-scroll>
```

Here is my code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGEpMN

Need to give height to `<ion-scroll` **total height -footer -header height** dynamically so that it will run on all windows.

Comment: You can do this with css: height: calc(100vh - FOOTERpx - HEADERpx)

Comment: could you use codepen

Comment: From what I see you have also style with height property on the ion-scroll which wins against the css selector

Comment: you can remove that sytle property .and that is also static value 100 px.I need to add dynamically so that it will run for all screen resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mrak said, you can do with calc like below:

```
ion-scroll[direction=y] {
  height: calc(100vh - 88px);
}
```

I can see your header and footer both have `44px` height so I used `88px` here.

Updated [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXNqzP)

Comment: I think it will not work for all resolution .because on small resolution the header and footer height decrease .I need such solution which run on all resolution

Comment: Then you can write media queries for that specific resolution and replace header and footer height based on the resolution.

Comment: It can be. I'm not sure but you are good to go with media queries.